# creating local class in ASCET

Tags: c

This actually is a Question about the Tool ASCET, I don't have enough rep to create this Tag so I used the tag for the language that runs below.

I want to create a class as a process local for holding variables that are used in sub functions of a Module.
[image]

What is it that I need to do so that this varibale is correctly initialized each time the process starts anew? because if i simply use the variable I get the error:

```
ERROR(MMdl821): read access to method local variable "locvar_1" prior to initialization of reference
```

I dont want locvar_1 to be a reference at all, I only need the reference for passing it to the sub-functions.

I need this Solution for the Block-Diagramm mode.

Comment: Since there is no ascet tag yet, it would be sensible to assume that there are very few if any questions on SO about it.  That in turn means you should probably provide at least a definitive URL for where information about the product can be found. In general, you should probably provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) for your problem.

Comment: I know that there a now ASCET questions her, but after asking around in my department, without result, I use every chance possible. The only place where you get info about the working behavior, that I know, of this Modellbased IDE is the HELP file that is shipped with ASCET. Providing a MCVE for this is also quit difficult because you would need quit a few Screenshots.

Comment: I found a number of questions (about 30) when I searched for `ascet`, but only one other mentioned ASCET; the others were mostly about 'ascetics' (usually, I think, a malaprop for aesthetics, though in one case at least probably a malaprop for agnostic).  The one that mentioned ASCET was more general, using ASCET as one of a number of examples.  So — congratulations: you are the first to ask about ASCET specifically.

Comment: Well want not is now, could be in the future^^ Anyway: Hope dies last